# What are some examples of parametrix solutions to PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[Wikipedia entry on the parametrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrix) is sparse on examples. I'm looking for a couple examples of this object for some simple PDEs to make sure I understand what it's talking about! (I don't have a book available).

Bonus points if you add them to the Wikipedia page for future readers.

Comment: [This Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316884/fundamental-solution-of-an-elliptic-pde-in-divergence-form-with-non-symmetric-ma/317373#317373) may help you in your search. In general, if you have a variable coefficients linear PDO, in order to construct its parametrix at a given point $x_o\in\Bbb R^n$ you should "freeze" its coefficients at that point and then determine the fundamental solution of the constant coefficient PDO you got.